# Can a user have multiple vnc sessions?

Tags: windows-10, debian, vncserver

I have a vps, and I usually connect it from my office and my home using vncviewer.

I find that, for the same user(e.g. john), I can only have one vnc session. If I already had a display(:1) at the office, when I try to connect to another display(:2), the 2nd display is a black screen.

Can the same user have different vnc sessions?

Comment: Is display `:2` on the VPS? What OS is the client? What OS is the VPS?

Comment: vnc is not the most robust option for doing this.  If it's windows, use remote desktop (problem goes away), if Linux, use x11 forwarding.. (problem goes away).  You will find that not only does the problem become less confusing, the performance is WAY WAY better.

Comment: @Burgi Yes, display:2 is on the VPS. Client OS is win10, VPS OS is Debian.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas My vps is Debian and client is win10. I used to use x11 forwarding in Mobaxterm. However, the connection automatically disconnect randomly( I have checked the option to "ssh keepalive"). So I switched to vnc, which does not disconnect.